# Probably database relationship cycle

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

My issue is related to a cycle relationship, where I need to solve the database schema in order to do the best practice, it will be used on a tracking vehicles system

My problem description:

1. A route could contain on or more fences, and a fence coul be contained by one or more routes
2. A route has assigned some vehicles ( consider that vehicles could be part or other routes )
3. When a route, which contain fences, has vehicle assigned, I need to control when a vehicle pass inside a fence; then I need to store if a fence is will set on each vehicle to compare when the vehicle get inside a fence

I have solved this issue on these way, but I ma not sure is it is a good practice, if no, **which one will be the best practice for this problem?**

[image: cycle problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 - A route could contain on or more fences, and a fence coul be contained by one or more routes

```
    Route --< RouteFenceRelationship >-- Fence

    "RouteFenceRelationship"
    PK RouteFenceRelationshipId
    FK RouteId
    FK FenceId
```

Many to many relationships don't work well, I'd heavily suggest a relationship table to define which routes contain which fences.

> 2 - A route has assigned some vehicles ( consider that vehicles could be part or other routes )

```
    Vehicle --< VehicleRouteRelationship >-- Route

    "VehicleRouteRelationship"
    PK VehicleRoutRelationshipId
    FK VehicleId
    FK RouteId
```

Same again here, relationship table to avoid the issues that come with a many to many relationship.

> 3 - When a route, which contain fences, has vehicle assigned, I need to control when a vehicle pass inside a fence; then I need to store if a fence is will set on each vehicle to compare when the vehicle get inside a fence

```
    Fence --< FenceVehiclePassEvent >-- Vehicle

    "FenceVehiclePassEvent"
    PK FenceVehiclePassEventId
    FK FenceId
    FK VehicleId
    Timestamp
```

I didn't really understand your third point, but you can add an entry in this table with the vehicle, the fence and the time that is passes through. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, first at all, you are right on using relational tables for ManyToMany, but I want to be sure of my logical idea is ok, well as you explain it is ok, but, this scheme is a good practice?

Comment: Ah ok, I understand what you mean now. You've got my head struggling around how to design this so that it isn't cyclic. I don't think that _this_ instance should give any issues, as it's they're not all 'has a' relationships; the vehicle-fence relationship is more of an event. True answer is that I don't really know if this is best practise, but more often that not if it makes logical sense, it's ok. Maybe someone else can shred some light on to the situation

Comment: If Route, Fence and Vehicle are share-able "entities" in your model then you can't use different design. The only other way would be denormalize tables and that is a bad idea for extensibility and consistency of the tables.